# ask the user for three names and print them in alphabetical order

Tags: java, string-comparison

Quote for Quote from the text: "Write a program that asks the user to enter three names, and then displays the names sorted in ascending order. For example, if the user entered "Charlie","Leslie, and "Andy", the program would display

```
Andy 
Charlie 
Leslie
```

My professor specifically said we are not allowed to use loops or arrays since we have not covered that in class. I have been trying to use the `compareTo` method but cant seem to get it to run with more than two string variables.

```
public class SortedNames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Declare Variables
        String name1;
        String name2;
        String name3;

        //Accept User Imput
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please Enter First Name ");
        name1=keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please Enter Second Name ");
        name2=keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please Enter Third Name ");
        name3=keyboard.nextLine();


        //Compare

        if((name2.compareToIgnoreCase(name1)<0)&&(name2.compareToIgnoreCase(name3)<0))
        {
            System.out.println(name2);
        }

        //Compare 

        if((name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name2)<0)&&(name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name3)<0))
        {
            System.out.println(name1);
        }

        //Compare

        if((name3.compareToIgnoreCase(name1)<0)&&(name3.compareToIgnoreCase(name2)<0))
        {
            System.out.println(name3);
        }
  }     

}
```

Comment: You're not supposed to try to make `compareTo` work with more than 2 strings.

Comment: How would you compare three numbers?

Comment: Crappy assignment... without arrays, you would have to write crappy code to keep comparing variables. Just use `Arrays.sort(stringArray, Collections.reverseOrder());`, dude.

Answer (score 7):

You have three strings, and you need to compare them and sort them accordingly. Let's use your example values:

```
String name1, name2, name3;
name1 = "Charlie";
name2 = "Leslie";
name3 = "Andy";
```

To keep things simple, there's one rule: You cannot simply "swap" the values. You'll need a temporary variable to hold the values you are swapping:

```
String temp;
```

Now, the comparisons. The way I would tackle this is by comparing the first name with the second and third name, and make the necessary swaps:

```
if(name1.compareTo(name2) > 0) { // "Charlie" > "Leslie" (this won't happen)
    temp = name1;    // temp = "Charlie"
    name1 = name2;   // name1 = "Leslie"
    name2 = temp;    // name2 = "Charlie"
}
if(name1.compareTo(name3) > 0) { // "Charlie" > "Andy" (this will happen)
    temp = name1;    // temp = "Charlie"
    name1 = name3;   // name1 = "Andy"
    name3 = temp;    // name3 = "Charlie"
}
/*
 * Up to this point:
 * name1 = "Andy"; name2 = "Leslie"; name3 = "Charlie"
 */
```

This way, you will ensure that the smallest of the three values is held at `name1`. Now, compare `name2` and `name3`, and swap them if necessary:

```
if(name2.compareTo(name3) > 0) { // "Leslie" > "Charlie" (this will happen)
    temp = name2;    // temp = "Leslie"
    name2 = name3;   // name2 = "Charlie"
    name3 = temp;    // name3 = "Leslie"
}
/*
 * Up to this point:
 * name1 = "Andy"; name2 = "Charlie"; name3 = "Leslie"
 */
```

And you are done.

Comment: As far as I can remember this is a "bubble sort"... quite inneficient, but enough for this

Answer (score 3):

Pseudocode

```
if s1 > s2 swap them
if s2 > s3 swap them
if s1 > s2 swap them
print s1, s2, s3
```

Comment: What I have written seems to work just not printing out all three names

Comment: @Harvey Forget printing until you are done with sorting. Concentrate on getting name1, name2 and name3 to contain the names in ascending order.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
import java.io.Console;

public final class SortNames
{
    private static final String PROMPT_FMT = "Enter %s name: ";
    private static final String NAME_FMT = "%s\n";

    private static final String FIRST = "1st";
    private static final String SECONDS = "2nd";
    private static final String THIRD = "3rd";

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Console console = System.console();
        if (console != null)
        {
            final SortNames sortNames = new SortNames(console);
            sortNames.run();
        } // if
        else
        {
            System.err.println("Sorry, no console.");
            System.exit(1);
        } // else
    } // main(String[])

    private final Console mConsole;

    private String mName1 = null;
    private String mName2 = null;
    private String mName3 = null;

    public SortNames(final Console console)
    {
        super();
        mConsole = console;
    } // constructor()

    private void run()
    {
        requestNames();
        sortNames();
        printNames();
    } // run()

    private void requestNames()
    {
        mName1 = requestName(FIRST);
        mName2 = requestName(SECONDS);
        mName3 = requestName(THIRD);
    } // requestNames()

    private String requestName(final String ordinal)
    {
        return mConsole.readLine(PROMPT_FMT, ordinal);
    } // requestName(String)

    private void sortNames()
    {
        sortNames1and2();
        if (sortNames2and3())
        {
            sortNames1and2();
        } // if
    } // sortNames()

    private void sortNames1and2()
    {
        if (greaterThan(mName1, mName2))
        {
            final String greater = mName1;
            mName1 = mName2;
            mName2 = greater;
        } // if
    } // sortNames1and2()

    private boolean sortNames2and3()
    {
        if (greaterThan(mName2, mName3))
        {
            final String greater = mName2;
            mName2 = mName3;
            mName3 = greater;
            return true;
        } // if
        return false;
    } // sortNames2and3()

    private void printNames()
    {
        printName(mName1);
        printName(mName2);
        printName(mName3);
    } // printNames()

    private void printName(final String name)
    {
        mConsole.format(NAME_FMT, name);
    } // printName(String)

    private static boolean greaterThan(final String s1, final String s2)
    {
        return s1.compareTo(s2) > 0;
    } // greaterThan(String, String)


} // class SortNames
```

Comment: Wow! A lot of boilerplate code for what? You are dealing with a novice that is already utterly confused. Hope your complex answer will not put him off from programming altogether!

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Needed for User Input

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    String name1;
    String name2;
    String name3;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter First Name ");
    name1=keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please Enter Second Name ");
    name2=keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please Enter Third Name ");
    name3=keyboard.nextLine();
    
    if((name1.compareTo(name2) < 0) && (name1.compareTo(name3) < 0))
        {
            System.out.println(name1);
            if (name2.compareTo(name3) < 0)
            {
                System.out.println(name2);
                System.out.println(name3);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(name3);
                System.out.println(name2);
            }
        }       
    else if((name1.compareTo(name2) > 0) && (name2.compareTo(name3) < 0))
        {
            System.out.println(name2);
            if (name1.compareTo(name3) < 0)
            {
                System.out.println(name1);
                System.out.println(name3);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(name3);
                System.out.println(name1);
            }
        }
    else 
        {
        System.out.println(name3);
            if (name1.compareTo(name2) < 0)
            {
                System.out.println(name1);
                System.out.println(name2);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(name2);
                System.out.println(name1);
            }
        }
    
}
```